# Late Landing at Athens and M3 Airport Line

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, safety, athens, ath

I will be landing at Athens Airport on a Friday evening around 23:00, and from [this page](http://www.stasy.gr/index.php?id=70&L=1), I see that the last train from airport is from 23:30. Are there no later trains on Fridays & Saturdays like [here (check Line 3)](http://www.stasy.gr/index.php?id=67&L=1)? Also how likely that I will miss that train? I will have to go through Visa check, though I will have no luggage.

---

Another question regarding the safety; I've heard about the presence of dangerous people on late night trains & buses.

How likely is it that the airport train would have such people? Also, after the train ride, I will have to walk from Monastiraki St. to Kotzia Square, some 600meters distance, at midnight. Would that also be dangerous?

Worst case scenario I will use the [X95 bus](https://www.athensairportbus.com/en/timetable/x95airporttoathensdowntown.html/), it is available till 23:55, but similarly how dangerous would it be to ride it that late? Also I'd have to walk a longer distance from Syntagma Square to Kotzia Square, how dangerous walking that route would be?

Sorry for so many questions! 
Σας ευχαριστώ πολύ για τη βοήθειά σας

Comment: You will most likely miss that train, as the Athens airport is heavily unorganized and usually quite chaotic in my experiences there. We have walked all over Monastiraki and Kotzia Square with a stroller and infant, on streets without sidewalks. It is relatively very safe, especially in those tourist areas. At the airport you can get a local taxi very easily or even an Uber (who is also a local taxi driver). The biggest danger on public transport is getting your wallet stolen, so keep it somewhere safe where they cannot easily pull it off you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got an answer from a native Athenian;

> Hey, I looked as well but didn't find any later trains from the
>   airport. Its going to be close but if not, you can take the bus. Both
>   are not dangerous, lot of people leaving the airport, you wont be
>   alone.
>
> As for the walk to Kotzia Square, there is no issue there as well.
>   Both stops are one of the central and busiest squares in Athens and
>   full of nightlife, and will be a lot of people outside. The whole area
>   actually is like that. Just stick to the bigger roads and you will
>   have no issue.